# Multiple "No resource found..." and "Error receiving parent for item" for fresh Xamarin project in VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I have created a new project for Xamarin in Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition 15.8.3. Then I added a few changes in the `MainPage.xaml` and `cs` and now I am getting these error on building the solution.

[image]

The errors refer to `styles.xml` which I didn't touch.

I was seeing this error earlier which required required restarting VS, rebooting computer, cleaning `obj` and `bin` directories, upgrading VS, etc.

I prefer to not do such things blindly.

Is there any systematic solution for this problem?

Comment: I was fighting this for half a day on a new project clean and build...  I decided this morning that I would open an example project, only to find that it was producing similar errors.  Try to Deploy it and see if that creates some additional resources that it thinks it is missing.

Comment: Just some additional questions that might help... What Android version are you targeting?  Is this a single project or cross-platform?

Comment: @kttii this doesn't matter. The problem can auto-cure without changing this

Comment: does your comment mean that you are no longer experiencing the problem?

Comment: It pops up from time to time. And when it does, I can't get rid of it by will, without woodoo.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in a VS2017 cross-platform solution targeting Android 7.1:

1. Clean your project and rebuild it.
2. Change each XAML file properties:
   Change the Build Action from "Embedded Resource" to "Compile" or "C# compiler"
3. Rebuild your project (it will produce errors)
4. Close VS2017 and delete the .VS folder and reopen solution
5. Change each XAML file properties:
   Change the Build Action back to "Embedded Resource"
6. Rebuild and it was good for me.

On a separate project, the solution above did not resolve my errors and I also performed these additional steps with success:

1. [Using this guide](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Diagnosing-Project-System-Build-Errors), I was able to determine that I was missing the following Nuget reference:

> ```
> Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat
> ```

2. After clean and build, close, delete .VS folder and reopen... I checked the log again and was able to determine that I was missing the following Nuget reference:

> ```
> Xamarin.Android.Support.Design
> ```

3. Another clean and build and those problems went away... leaving me with remnant code issues that I was able to resolve.
4. After another clean and build... I received another error that I was missing the following Nuget reference:

> ```
> Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView
> ```

5. Another clean and build... no errors.

Comment: @Dims I updated my answer, which shows I was missing references on another project.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

See if you have not change any of this in the **MainPage.xaml**

If not put here your content in that page just to see if anyone see the error.

Comment: No, I din't change it, only nested code, which has nothing "criminal". It's toolset problem.